# sbt server not available

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to get the play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial working, but it does not work.

I have downloaded the java Hello world from https://www.playframework.com/getting-started
In the readme is decribed that I should run sbt.bat. It downloaded several maven dependencies and started a server, but I cannot access it.

Now running sbt.bat :

```
C:\play\play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial>.\sbt-dist\bin\sbt.bat
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading settings for project play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\play\play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial\project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to play-java-hello-world-web (in build file:/C:/play/play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial/)
[info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-134f36618ffbf47c6676
[play-java-hello-world-web] $
```

The readme tells me :
3. After the message `Server started, ...` displays, enter the following URL in a browser: http://localhost:9000

But it does not serve a webpage. I allready disabled the firewall and tried to run another webserver on port 9000, which works.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The sbt server is not the same as the play framework server. You only started the sbt console. You need to start the real server with the command `run`. Then it will available on port 9000.